# Trying to my homescreen have no tabs and to have the rest of my app use the tabnavigator

Tags: react-native

Here is my tabNav where I am trying to load HomeStackNav, however there are tabs under my homescreen component when I do it this way.

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {screen: HomeStackNav},
  Dashboard: { screen: DashboardStackNav },
  Add: {screen: AddStackNav},
  Profile: { screen: ProfileStackNav },
}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'salmon',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#c0c1c4',
    inactiveTintColor: '#f4af55',
    inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
    labelOptions: {
      fontSize: 10,
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },


  }
})
```

I tried to implement navigationoptions here and within the homescreen component to hide the tabs, but with no success.

```
const HomeStackNav = StackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
    tabBarVisible: false
  }
})

export default HomeStackNav;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
navigationOptions: {
  tabBarVisible: false
}
```

As part of your `TabNavigator`

```
HomeScreen: {screen: HomeStackNav}
```

So

```
HomeScreen: {
  screen: HomeStackNav,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarVisible: false
  }
}
```

As you are referring to the root navigation.